# subfigure crop figures at the end of page

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I'm trying to include a set of 8 figures into a single figure with `subfigure`, but they are too big to fit in one page all together,  and they get cropped.

I want to keep them all in the same figure environment but in different pages so they preserve their size.

Comment: Which package do you use `subcaption` or `subfig`?

Comment: One figure cannot span more than one page.  However, if you use only one \caption, or multiple \caption{...}\addtocounter{figure}{-1} you can use the same figure number for each figure (the list of figures will probably get confused).

Comment: I'm using `subfigure'

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with \addtocounter{figure}{-1} and setting the counter of the subfigures as well with \setcounter{subfigure}{n}.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\ContinuedFloat` command of the `subfig` package.

In the preamble load it like:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

and then in the text:

```
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[caption 1]{\includegraphic{fig-1} } \,
  \subfloat[caption 2]{\includegraphic{fig-2} } \,
  \subfloat[caption 3]{\includegraphic{fig-3} } \,
  %load as many figures until one page is filled
\end{figure}
```

and then, to proceed on the following page

```
\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[caption 4]{\includegraphic{fig-1} } \,
  \caption{Caption for the 4 subfloats}
\end{figure}
```